# Подключение платежей телеграм бот Java

Tags: java, telegram-bot

Разбираюсь с телеграм ботом, не могу понять почему не выводится предложение для покупки.

Пытаюсь сделать так:

```
execute(SendInvoice.builder()
                    .chatId(id)
                    .currency("RUB")
                    .providerToken("401643678:TEST:3947e67a-cf1f-4db4-967c-1beae96df73d")
                    .title("Тест")
                    .description("Тест")
                    .payload("Тест")
                    .price(new LabeledPrice("Тест",100000000))
                    .build());
```

Вроде, сделано так, как указано в документации, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: По какой документации вы делали? https://core.telegram.org/bots/payments#supported-currencies

Comment: Вы, конечно, разогнались, max amount — 730 649,04 RUB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В соответствии с документацией [Bot Payments API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/payments#supported-currencies), минимальная цена в рублях — 73,06 RUB, максимальная — 730 649,04 RUB.

В вашем примере цена выходит за пределы этого диапазона.